# SpringViewProvider for Spring UI in Vaadin

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I am trying to implement spring views in my vaadin application but I get an NPE on my SpringViewProvider ("Cannot add a null view provider"). This is my code:

```
@SpringUI(path = "permalink")
@Theme("myTheme")
public class PermalinkUI extends UI {

@Autowired
private SpringViewProvider springViewProvider;

private Navigator navigator;

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

  final VerticalLayout root = new VerticalLayout();
  root.setSizeFull();
  root.setMargin(true);
  root.setSpacing(true);
  setContent(root);

  final Panel viewContainer = new Panel();
  viewContainer.setSizeFull();
  root.addComponent(viewContainer);
  root.setExpandRatio(viewContainer, 1.0f);


  navigator = new Navigator(this, viewContainer);
  navigator.addProvider(springViewProvider);
  setNavigator(navigator);

  setContent(root);
```

I have also tried to use a ViewDisplay instead of a single component container (root) but with the same result. I have also implemented a test view to navigate to:

```
@SpringView(name = "test")
public class PermalinkTest extends VerticalLayout implements View {


@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {
  removeAllComponents();
  String params = event.getParameters();
  addComponent(new Label(params));
 }
}
```

I get this NPE when writing this URL "localhost:8080/permalink/test.
What am I missing? Shouldn't the SpringViewProvider be autowired?

Regards Johan

Comment: Views are accesed with `#!` prefix, so, give a try with `localhost:8080/permalink/#!test` and see if it works. Without the prefix, what you are trying to access is a UI with `/permalink/test` path mapped, not a view.

Answer (score 3):

When using `vaadin-spring-2.0.0`, `SpringNavigator` is a managed `@UIScope`-ed bean so it can be injected directly. (You don't have to inject `SpringViewProvider` at all if you otherwise don't need it.)

Besides, you have to manually initialize the `SpringNavigator` instance to prevent `NullPointerException`:

```
@SpringUI
public class SampleUi extends UI {

    @Inject
    private SpringNavigator navigator;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        navigator.init(this, this); // Explicit init() call
        navigator.navigateTo(StartView.NAME);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Autowiring should work as soon as you setup the Vaadin - Spring integration correctly.

E.g. the WebServlet must extend SpringVaadinServlet:

```
@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
public static class PermalinkUIServlet extends SpringVaadinServlet{

        @Override
        protected void servletInitialized() throws ServletException {
            super.servletInitialized();
            ...
        }
    }
```

Also have a look at https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Vaadin+Spring

Comment: Hi. Sorry for not being more specific but I have two uis "separated" by a UIProvider (annotated on my Spring Vaadin servlet) and the autowiring works perfect on the other ui (autowiring for other beans because that ui doesn't have a SpringViewProvider)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use SpringViewProvider manually you need to send it through a constructor just like this:

```
@SpringUI
@Theme(ValoTheme.THEME_NAME)
public class NavigationUI extends UI {

    private final SpringViewProvider viewProvider;

    @Autowired
    public NavigationUI(SpringViewProvider viewProvider) {
        this.viewProvider = viewProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        final VerticalLayout root = new VerticalLayout();
        root.setSizeFull();
        root.setMargin(true);
        root.setSpacing(true);
        setContent(root);
...
```

This example was taken from official Spring4Vaadin project - https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring

Answer (score 0):

Which Spring Vaadin Version are you using? I can sugest you just just go for simple navigator and add viewProvider:

```
@Autowired
SpringViewProvider viewProvider;

Navigator navi = new Navigator(this,this);
navi.addViewProvider(viewProvider);
navi.setErrorView(ErrorView.class);
```

This works well in both versions 1.0.0 and 1.1.1, however this trick doesn't work with SpringNavigator (1.1.1)